# Why is Port 8333 open on my android phone

Tags: android, linux, networking, port, nmap

I was scanning my android phone to find some open ports using nmap today which is apart of my class, what I found was normal ports that where always open as usual but then I came across a port I've never seen before which is port 8333

[image: Output of scan]

through my research I have found out it is a bitcoin node port, but what I would like to know is why is it open and could it be a significant risk to my phone if I leave it open

Phone Model: Samsung Galaxy S9
OS: Android

Comment: maybe it's some app related with bitcoin.. or some app mining bitcoin... https://www.speedguide.net/port.php?port=8333

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving `port 8333` **open** is a **security flaw** that can be exploited by anyone who can get your `IP` and log open ports. (This port is normally used for mining Bitcoin, but anyone can use an open port as he wants it to be)

The problems this could cause are a significant `reduction of your network`, `continuous battery operation`, and `overheating` of your equipment as it will `use` and `block` most of your `RAM`.

### To counter this:

Use a `virtual private network (VPN)` or a `firewall`.

I hope I was able to help you.